# Regular expression - replace multiple html tags with one

Tags: javascript, html, regex

is there a regular expression or any way to replace the following:

```
  some content...<span style='color:red'>t</span><span style='color:red'>e</span><span style='color:red'>s</span><span style='color:red'>t</span> some content
```

with this?

```
some content... <span style='color:red'>test</span> some content
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 6):

If the HTML tags are all the same, you can just use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var oldStr = "<span style='color:red'>t</span><span style='color:red'>e</span><span style='color:red'>s</span><span style='color:red'>t</span>";
var newStr = oldStr.replace("</span><span style='color:red'>", "");
```

Comment: I am upvoting because you are not used regex eventhough OP want it in Regex. Because Don't use Regex to parse HTML and I appreciate you for this answer

Comment: the problem with this solution is what if there is an unrelated span end tag before the first color span tag

Answer (score 0):

There are opinions that regex should not be used to process HTML.

If you agree, you can use the following XSLT transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat"
    encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Copy attributes and text from the current span -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="nextSpans" select="following-sibling::span"/>
      <!-- Copy text from following spans -->
      <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node()">
        <xsl:variable name="ind" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($nextSpans[$ind])">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Switch off processing of "following" spans -->
  <xsl:template match="span[preceding-sibling::node()[1]/name()='span']"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```